# mongodb query opposite of $all

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to learn MongoDB and it's been awesome so far. However I ran into a situation and I'm not too sure how to solve it. Hopefully someone could help me out and thanks in advance.

I wanted to get records that the (entire) array value is within the query. For example:

**record 1 :**

```
{"name" : "Mango Shake", 
 "ingredients" : [{"type" : "fruit", "name" : "mango"},
                  {"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"}]}
```

**record 2 :**

```
{"name" : "Mango Banana Shake", 
 "ingredients" : [{"type" : "fruit", "name" : "mango"},
                  {"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"},
                  {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "banana"}]}
```

**record 3:**

```
{"name" : "Milk Shake", 
 "ingredients" : [{"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"}]}
```

then i would have a query something like

```
{"ingredients" : {$all : [{"type" : "fruit", "name" : "mango"},
                          {"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"},
                          {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "strawberry"}]}}
```

because I have **"mango"**, **"soy milk"** and **"strawberry"**. So I wanted to know which shakes I can do. Apparently this doesn't return anything because the query cannot have extra stuff. If I use `$in` then all will return, but I cannot do mango banana shake because I don't have a banana..

So what I only need is the first and last one. Any idea? Appreciate it :)

Comment: So, you want to form a query from those ingredients that you do have on hand, thereby returning a result set that includes only those shakes that you could make?

Comment: yes exactly.. thanks chb

Comment: do you have any requirements like it should only be a single query? can i just return the name/id?

Comment: Really good question, only way it can be achieved is by using $where and checking and for each document check if ingredient is subset of they array you are looking for. tedious but achievable.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way to do this with find. But you could do it with a [mapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce).

Your map function would iterate the ingredients of the currently examined document and only emit it when all fields are ingredients you have. You don't need a reduce function for this, so the key of the emitted values should be the _id of the drink documents.

When the keys are unique, the reduce function should never be called (the reduce function is used to determine what happens when multiple values are emitted for the same key). I don't think that you can just omit the reduce function, so you should write one which just returns the first element of the values array.

Answer (score 0):

Map reduce will work if you like, or you can simply use $and with one condition for each of your ingredients:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/and/

I've used $and before for similar query needs. Unfortunately, in both cases this will have to check against each and every recipe document every time you query which will have serious performance implications if your collection gets large.

This may be better handled with a relational database. At the very least you should consider keeping a separate queryable index of ingredients that have a map to the recipe id's that use them. Then you could retrieve just the ingredients you have and take the intersection of the recipes in code. Again, since this is actually something a relational database can do for you it may simply be the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) to access specific elements of the array and check that each element is `$in` your available ingredients list and you could construct an `$and` query to do that for each element in the document being queried BUT of course *that will not work* since you don't know how many elements are in each recipe's ingredients list.

One solution to that problem is to add an array to each document that is a fixed size (maybe 3 elements) into which you put the n-least common ingredients from the recipe, padding (with repeats if necessary to fill the array).  Now you can do a query using `$and` and `$in` against each element of that array.  This will find all the recipes that 'might' be possible, and since you stored the least common ingredients it should do a good job filtering out recipes you can't make.  You can then do the final filter client-side.

Sometimes adding a different representation of the data can be a good way to solve a tricky query problem like this, and sometimes a combination of server and client-side filtering may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript function as a find parameter. However, I think MapReduce would be a much more elegant solution overall due to scalability, and the general uneasiness that comes with inserting user input into code that is executed.

Here is an example query that would be constructed. Basically, it filters the item's ingredients and checks that the filtered list is the same length as the original ingredient list:

```
db.shakes.find(function() {

  // Implant your query JSON object here
  var query_obj = [{"type" : "fruit", "name" : "mango"},
                   {"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"},
                   {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "strawberry"}];  
  return this.ingredients.filter(function(ingredient) {
    var has_ingredients = false;
    query_obj.forEach(function(query) {
      has_ingredients |= (query.type == ingredient.type && query.name == ingredient.name);
    });
    return has_ingredients;
  }).length === this.ingredients.length;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There no direct way to do this. you can build a simple javascript function to solve your query by looking each document and checking of array ingredients has all three ingredients.

```
db.shakes.find().forEach(

function (shakes) {
    for (i = 0; i < shakes.ingredients.length; i++) {
        switch (shakes.ingredients[i].name) {
        case "banana":
            var count = 1;
        case "soy milk":
            count++;
        case "mango":
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 3) {
            print(shakes.name);
        }
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To bring some new idea, in the case you have a already known set of all the ingredients. For instance the possible ingredients are just 5:

```
["mango","soy milk", "strawberry", "banana", "pineapple"]
```

And you dont' have neither banana nor pineapple

One option is to query for the ingredients you don't have:

```
{"ingredients" : {$nin : [{"type" : "fruit", "name" : "banana"},
                          {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "pineapple"}]}}
```

This returns all the documents that don't have ingredient that you don't have, so, the recieps with ingredients you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are ok with the [caveats of using the `$where` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations), you can use it, in combination with [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to obtain the desired results.

This looks like a javascript-specific solution, but it is not. The javascript is injected directly into Mongo (V8). All language drivers should support it. I know at least that [PHP does](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocode.php).

You should be able to paste this code directly into the [Mongo REPL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#executing-queries) and get the results you expect (knock on wood).

If your milkshake database has the potential to scale beyond what `$where` can give you, [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is your friend.

```
var query = {
    "$where": function() {
        var myIngredients = [
            {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "mango"},
            {"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"},
            {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "strawberry"}
        ];
        return obj.ingredients.every(function(milkShakeIngredient){
            return myIngredients.some(function(myIngredient){
                return ( milkShakeIngredient.name === myIngredient.name &&  milkShakeIngredient.type === myIngredient.type );
            });
        });
    }
};

db.milkShakes.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation pipelines for that.

With [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) create the `missing` element which contains the missing ingredients ([$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/index.html) will help you to get the missing ingredients) for the current shake. Then with [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) filter out all shakes which do not have the missing ingredients.

Query example:

```
db.getCollection('shakes').aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            'missing': {
                $setDifference: [
                    "$ingredients",
                    [
                        {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "mango"},
                        {"type" : "milk", "name" : "soy milk"},
                        {"type" : "fruit", "name" : "strawberry"}
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { $match: {'missing': []} }
])
```